# How add a 404/Catch all navigation Routes in Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have several routes that are not yet implemented fully but need to have buttons/links defined.

How I can get a "404" route that display them instead of crashing?

```kotlin
 NavHost(
        navController = nav,
        startDestination = NavRoutes.Splash.route,
    ) {
        composable(NavRoutes.Home.route) {
            To(nav = nav, Request.Home(ctx = ctx))
        }
        // How have this?
        composable(NavRoutes.Errors.404) {
            To(nav = nav, Request.Error(route = ???))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just curious can you do that when not using compose ? I started android development with compose so I don't know

Comment: The issues is not with compose. Is easy to switch to a else clause. Is when using NavHost that is not clear to me how to do it.

Comment: Did you end up finding a way?